# Cancel() and periodic scheduled task

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

From the Android Dev Reference:

```
public abstract boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)

If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter
determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in
an attempt to stop the task.
```

This is clear for me, when talking about tasks that happen only once. But not, when I have a periodic task, and I want to let it finish the current "task", but not start a new one.

Is it right, that I can use neither of those straight out-of-the-box? I think if I set the argument to true, it can stop the current task before it has finished, and if I change it to false, and there is a task currently running, it does nothing. Is this right?

How would I implement what I wanted? Should I somehow poll the task to find if it is running, and cancel it when I find it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your environment in detail but as far as I understand you're using some executor from `java.util.concurrent` with which periodic task is scheduled.

Basically parameter of `cancel()` determines whether to terminate running thread forcibly. If it is set to false than it just lets programmer to decide when to interrupt running thread by checking `isCanceled()` (speaking of something derived from `Future` and `Runnable`).

So calling `cancel(false)` method of `SheduledFuture` returned by `Executor` should work for you. This will not interrupt running task and prevent it from running again. After calling it, `Future.get()` will throw an exception which will cause an executor not to run it next scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29):

```
... ...
// At some point in the future if you want reject next periodic task submit
// after waiting for current periodic task finish.
scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown(); // <-- this will reject next periodic task submit.
scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // <-- this will wait current periodic task finish.
... ...
```

awaitTermination() must be called after shutdown(), which is not clearly stated from Android API, however, you can find the detailed documentation from [official Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).